# Enclosing shortcodes create line breaks

Tags: shortcode

I created enclosing shortcodes like this:

```
//[rezept]
function rezept_func( $atts, $content = null ){
    return '<div class="drl-rezept-wrapper">'.do_shortcode($content).'</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'rezept', 'rezept_func' );

function rezept_zutaten_func( $atts, $content = null ){
    return '<div class="drl-rezept-left">'.$content.'</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'rezept-zutaten', 'rezept_zutaten_func' );
```

The HTML code is:

```
[rezept]
[rezept-zutaten]
<span>Zutat 1</span>
<span>Zutat 2</span>
<span>Zutat 3</span>
[/rezept-zutaten]
[/rezept]
```

The result is this html code:

```
<div class="drl-rezept-wrapper"><br>
<div class="drl-rezept-left"><br>
<span>Zutat 1</span><br>
<span>Zutat 2</span><br>
<span>Zutat 3</span><br>
</div><br>
<br>
</div>
```

Where are all the `<br>'s` are coming from and how can I remove them?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Can you `trim()` the `<br>` from `do_shortcode` before you return the content? `strip_tags` can also limit tags in the final output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just strip the `<br />` from the content then you could modify your function to replace that signature with an empty string. It feels like a dirty hack, but it's working for me.

It's worth noting that my Chrome tools show `<br>` but the actual code is rendering `<br />` which is what the expression is checking against.

```
//[rezept]
function rezept_func( $atts, $content = null ) {

    // remove '<br />'
    $no_br = preg_replace( "/(<br\s\/>)/", "", do_shortcode( $content ) );
    return '<div class="drl-rezept-wrapper">' . $no_br . '</div>';
}

add_shortcode( 'rezept', 'rezept_func' );

function rezept_zutaten_func( $atts, $content = null ) {

    // remove '<br />'
    $no_br = preg_replace( "/(<br\s\/>)/", "", $content );
    return '<div class="drl-rezept-left">' . $no_br . '</div>';
}

add_shortcode( 'rezept-zutaten', 'rezept_zutaten_func' );
```

The reason this is happening is there is a [`wpautop`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop) filter on the `$content` before it reaches your shortcode. You can actually disable all extra `<br />` and `<p>` tags by adding:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

And you can enable the `p` without `br` by registering our own filter:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop_no_br' );

function wpautop_no_br ($content, $br){
    return wpautop($content, false);
}
```

Although if you were to disable [`wpautop`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop) then you're affecting more than just your shortcode which is not recommended. To see the difference take a look at the output from these blocks.

```
echo '<pre>RAW</pre><pre>'
     . get_post( get_the_ID() )->post_content
     . '</pre>';

echo '<pre>Filtered</pre><pre>'
     . wpautop( get_post( get_the_ID() )->post_content )
     . '</pre>';

echo '<pre>Filtered - No BR</pre><pre>'
     . wpautop( get_post( get_the_ID() )->post_content, false )
     . '</pre>';
```

Comment: That isn't a good idea to removing `br` tag for whole WP editor!

Comment: Sure... but the OP wanted to know why this existed in the first place. That's where it's coming from. You could argue `strip_tags` is just as bad because you're required to know and define what is allowed ahead of time.

Answer (score -1):

`<br />` tags coming from the content editor. You added line breaks which are converted to `<br />` tags.

Use your shortcode in this way

```
[rezept][rezept-zutaten]<span>Zutat 1</span><span>Zutat 2</span><span>Zutat 3</span>[/rezept-zutaten][/rezept]
```

OR as per @jgraup suggestion you can use `strip_tags` to allow only certain tags.

```
function rezept_func( $atts, $content = null ){
    $content = strip_tags($content, '<span><p>');
    return '<div class="drl-rezept-wrapper">'.do_shortcode($content).'</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'rezept', 'rezept_func' );
```

Remember now user will never be able to add `<br />` tags in content. The best to let user understand that WordPress convert line break in `<br />`.

Comment: That works in a certain manner, but this is will not work for my client. It should be in a readable format. Any other possibility?

Comment: Updated answer please check!

Comment: I meant so say that `br` tags coming from editor because of line breaks! `>>You added line breaks which are converted to <br /> tags.` Of course raw content only have line breaks. I am sorry I did not get what do you mean ?

Comment: There is no possibility that `<br>` Tags after shortcodes are not added to the code? I think its totally fine to have `<br>'s* after Zutat 1, Zutat 2 etc, but not after the shortcodes...Also i think that makes no sense...

Comment: @Torben I am not sure what your client want! it is content, like a design there is no logic at all. Now you know where `<br />` coming from how to remove them by code or in content. Rest you can do yourself.